# Second express.static not working online

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean

I have my code locally working well, but when I pull my code on my digitalocean web server, my  code doesn't work like locally.

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dynamicApp'));
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/staticApp'));
});
```

When I try to access content in /staticApp it works locally, but it doesn't on my digital ocean server. Content in the /dynamicApp work properly.

Both environment have the same node.js version (0.10.17), I have loaded with Vim my server files, and they are the same. I have done ls in all folders, and the structure is the same. I tried in incognito mode in Chrome to see if it were caching issues, and the issue is still there.

Anyone has a clue why this could happen ?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I too, am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the paths that serve the static content like:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
   app.use('/dynamicApp', express.static(__dirname + '/dynamicApp'));
   app.use('/staticApp', express.static(__dirname + '/staticApp'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### express 4.x , like this:

> app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
>
> app.use('/data', express.static(__dirname+'/data'));